# Index Optimize Exclude a particular table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

We have a maintenance plan that uses the 'IndexOptimize' stored procedure from http://ola.hallengren.com/ .
 I would like to exclude one table from the SP and create a stand alone job for just this one which is simple and straight forward.

My question is, how can I exclude this particular table 'DWProd.dbo.Exclude_Tbl' from the original IndexOptimize that traverses through all the databases and tables? 
Thanks
SD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can exclude tables like this:

```
@Indexes = 'ALL_INDEXES, -Db1.Schema1.Tbl1'
```

Reference: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html#Indexes

Comment: Hello @OlaHallengren - The Index Maintenance script is failing with error for a table "Transaction (Process ID 120) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction." In the event of such error, the script is failing but I want to ignore the table/index that caused this and proceed tending other indexes. Please tell if it can be done? if yes what flag to be used?